# Django Form Reject Input if Specific User uses the same name twice and notifies user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

In Django, I have a custom form that creates an "email group" within a modal. The email group model contains a number of attributes, including a unique ID for the email group, for the user, etc.

The idea is that a specific user shouldn't be able to enter the same name twice - and if they do, they should be notified.

It seems right now like the form is rejecting inputs that duplicate email_name (it doesn't get added to the database), but the message it's returning is New Email Added.

I've also been trying to get the email to show within the modal but that's a whole other issue.

form.py

```
class EmailCreateForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = UserEmail
    fields = ['email_name']
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user_id', 'email_name'], name='unique_name')
    ]

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EmailCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Call to ModelForm constructor
    self.fields['email_name'].widget.attrs['rows'] = 1
```

views.py

```
def email(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EmailCreateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)


    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, f'New Email Added')
        return redirect('project-emails')
    else:
        messages.error(request, f'Email not Added')
        return redirect('project-emails')


else:
    form = EmailCreateForm()
return render(request, 'project/emails.html', {'form': form})
```

part of template emails.html

```
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert id = 'email-message'">
        {{ message|escape }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: could you please share your model ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/):

> The classes defined in this module create database constraints. They are added in the model Meta.constraints option.

So, this should be added to the model class, not form.

Thus, your `form.is_valid()` will return true and the success message will be displayed. If you set unique constraints on the model class they should be checked in `ModelForm` instances in both steps: when validating the form and when saving to DB.